# Inline custom CSS in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a simple button component

```
  <Button 
    bsStyle={!isClicked ? "default" : "warning"}
    className="plate-well"
    onMouseOver = {this.handleMouseDownOver}
    onMouseDown = {this.handleMouseDownOver}
    style={wellStyle}
  />
```

and I am trying to apply some custom CSS using a conical gradient:

```
const wellStyle = {
  background: "conic-gradient(lime 40%, yellow 0 70%, red 0) !important"
}
```

When I include this in my stylesheet directly it works fine:

```
.plate-well {
  background: conic-gradient(lime 40%, yellow 0 70%, red 0) !important;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

But it does not work when I include it as an inline style on my component. I'm wondering why my component is exhibiting this behavior and how to modify the inline style through react?

Comment: Where does your `Button` component come from?

Comment: Try `const wellStyle = "background: conic-gradient(lime 40%, yellow 0 70%, red 0) !important"`

Comment: @Tholle Button is a react-boostrap component.

Answer (score 0):

`conic-gradient` property is not fully implemented in barely any browser (only Chrome 69 onwards). Please check the [Implementation](https://caniuse.com/#search=conic). I would suggest using [Lea Verou's Pollyfill](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/).

Comment: Thanks, I have included the polyfill which allows the implementation in the .css file. So, the feature is working given the added js (and css) but not using the inline style.